# are codeigniter validation callbacks safe?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

Ok so I have noticed that codeigniter's "form_validation" library allows the use of callbacks which is great but their is one condition, the method has to be declared public.

Everyone who has used codeigniter will know that a public method in a controller will be accessible from the outside world, I even tried to to see if codeigniter had some code to stop you invoking callback methods and it doesn't.

How much of a security risk is this because I don't feel so safe being so open.

Thanks,
 Dan

Comment: Use Callable. Problem solved and yes i agree with you - no public methods in controllers - and further i prefer Thin Controllers so i put all that fatty form validation code in a model. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think it's unsafe. What I always will do is just have the form also send some extra value along, such as CSRF token which you can validate, along with another unique value created when you get inside the main validating function which both you can validate in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make `MY_Form_validation.php` library and set custom validation methods with use behind paranoia.

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'BASEPATH' ) ) exit( 'Not your cup of tea.' );

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function noone_can_see($str)
    {
        if ( (string)$str !== (string)strrev($str) )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|noone_can_see', ['noone_can_see' => 'We still can not read the %s identically from both ways.']);
```

Loading library is not changed. Still can be in `autoload.php` with `'form_validation'` value of library array.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same thought, and I tried calling a callback function from an HTTP request from a web browser successfully.
 I have fount it pretty usafe, expecially because my callback executes a model query using input data. 
One thing you can do is use callable instead or block access to callback functions:
[How to disable direct access to callback functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683205/how-to-disable-direct-access-to-callback-functions)